# Error while connecting to RStudio Server

Tags: apt, server, r, rstudio

I am trying to install RStudio Server in my ubuntu server (16.04) and whenever i do so, I am seeing the following message:

```
***sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb***

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 38, in <module>
        from GDebi.GDebiCli import GDebiCli
      File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 24, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
    Error in sys.excepthook:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
        from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from apport.report import Report
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
        import apport.fileutils
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 25, in <module>
        from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
    
    Original exception was:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 38, in <module>
        from GDebi.GDebiCli import GDebiCli
      File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 24, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
    (base) root@unigel:~# cd ^C
    (base) root@unigel:~# sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 38, in <module>
        from GDebi.GDebiCli import GDebiCli
      File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 24, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
    Error in sys.excepthook:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
        from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from apport.report import Report
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
        import apport.fileutils
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 25, in <module>
        from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
    
    Original exception was:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/gdebi", line 38, in <module>
        from GDebi.GDebiCli import GDebiCli
      File "/usr/share/gdebi/GDebi/GDebiCli.py", line 24, in <module>
        import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

The command I used for installation is this: sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb
I also tried by typing: sudo dpkg -i rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb   and didnt work well either.

FYI, the second command returned the following result:

```
(Reading database ... 1925 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-server-1.4.1103-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio-server (1.4.1103) over (1.4.1103) ...
Setting up rstudio-server (1.4.1103) ...
useradd: user 'rstudio-server' already exists
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rstudio-server.service to /lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service.
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-02-10 15:59:13 KST; 1s ago
  Process: 7202 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7210 (rserver)
    Tasks: 3
   Memory: 9.6M
      CPU: 562ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
           └─7210 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver

 Feb 10 15:59:12 xxxxx systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
 Feb 10 15:59:13 xxxxx systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
 Feb 10 15:59:13 xxxxx rserver[7210]: ERROR Unable to find libR.so in expected ...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Since 16.04 is EOL in April of this year the first thing you might want to do is upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04 after that try again.

Comment: @David: Ubuntu 16.04 ESM is supported until April 2024. ESM is not automatic.

Comment: Sorry I do not see where it says ESM. Yes I know that has extended support.